# Swap column values based on a condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to relocate columns by condition.
In case country is 'Japan',  I need to relocate last_name and first_name reverse.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['France','Kylian', 'Mbappe'],
               ['Japan','Hiroyuki', 'Tajima'],
               ['Japan','Shiji', 'Kagawa'],
               ['England','Harry', 'Kane'],
               ['Japan','Yuya', 'Ohsako'],
               ['Portuguese','Cristiano', 'Ronaldo']],
              columns=['country', 'first_name', 'last_name'])
```

Current output is

```
      country first_name last_name
0      France     Kylian    Mbappe
1       Japan   Hiroyuki    Tajima
2       Japan      Shiji    kagawa
3     England      Harry      Kane
4       Japan       Yuya    Ohsako
5  Portuguese  Cristiano   Ronaldo
```

I would like to make it following.

```
      country first_name last_name
0      France     Kylian    Mbappe
1       Japan     Tajima  Hiroyuki
2       Japan     Kagawa    Shinji
3     England      Harry      Kane
4       Japan     Ohsako      Yuya
5  Portuguese  Cristiano   Ronaldo
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
### check below   


 df['first_name'],df['last_name']=np.where(df['country']=='Japan',(df['last_name'],df['first_name']),(df['first_name'],df['last_name']))
```

### output:

```
   country      first_name     last_name
0   France      Kylian         Mbappe
1   Japan       Tajima         Hiroyuki
2   Japan       Kagawa         Shiji
3   England     Harry          Kane
4   Japan       Ohsako         Yuya
5   Portuguese  Cristiano  Ronaldo
```

Answer (score 11):

Use `loc` and swap the "first_name" and "last_name" values for rows whose "country" matches "Japan".

```
m = df['country'] == 'Japan'

df.loc[m, ['first_name', 'last_name']] = (
    df.loc[m, ['last_name', 'first_name']].values)
df    

      country first_name last_name
0  France      Kylian     Mbappe  
1  Japan       Tajima     Hiroyuki
2  Japan       Kagawa     Shiji   
3  England     Harry      Kane    
4  Japan       Ohsako     Yuya    
5  Portuguese  Cristiano  Ronaldo
```

---

Another option using `rename` and `update`:

```
mp = {'first_name': 'last_name', 'last_name': 'first_name'}
df.update(df.loc[m].rename(mp, axis=1))
df

      country first_name last_name
0  France      Kylian     Mbappe  
1  Japan       Tajima     Hiroyuki
2  Japan       Kagawa     Shiji   
3  England     Harry      Kane    
4  Japan       Ohsako     Yuya    
5  Portuguese  Cristiano  Ronaldo
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `np.where`

```
mask = df['country']=='Japan'

df['first_name1'] = np.where(mask, df['last_name'], df['first_name'])
df['last_name'] = np.where(mask, df['first_name'], df['last_name'])

df['first_name'] = df['first_name1']

df.drop('first_name1', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
    country first_name  last_name
0   France  Kylian  Mbappe
1   Japan   Tajima  Hiroyuki
2   Japan   Kagawa  Shiji
3   England Harry   Kane
4   Japan   Ohsako  Yuya
5   Portuguese  Cristiano   Ronaldo
```

Comment: Instead of `df['first_name'] = df['first_name1']`, you can just .`rename` the column. You should also consider computing the condition with "country" just once and saving it to something for reuse.

Comment: but `first_name1` column will still be there, am I right?

Comment: `df.rename({'first_name1': 'first_name'}, axis=1)` will just rename the column (not duplicate it). Which is better than creating a new one and dropping the old.

Comment: @cs95  then my df will have 2 columns with name `first_name`.

Comment: I see your point. One suggestion would be to `df['last_name'] = np.where(mask, df.pop('first_name'), df.pop('last_name'))` and then renaming would be fine. But at this point there is too much going on. Perhaps this is fine as-is.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df['last_name1']=df.last_name
df.loc[df.country=='Japan','last_name']=df[df.country=='Japan']['first_name']
df.loc[df.country=='Japan','first_name']=df[df.country=='Japan']['last_name1']
df=df.drop(['last_name1'],axis=1)
```